# How do I make a locale available in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, collation

I needed to add new locales to our postgresql server (PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit ).
As the locales were not yet installed on Ubuntu, I added them with

`sudo locale-gen fr_FR.UTF-8`

the locales do show now with

`locale -a`

I restarted the postgresql server, but the locales aren't visible in postgresql. I cant find themp in `select * from pg_collation;`

When I try to create the collation manually with `create collation fr_FR (LOCALE=‘fr_FR.utf8’)`, I get this error

`ERROR:  could not create locale "‘tr_tr.utf8’": Success`

Am I missing a step ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a syntax problem. This statement:

```
create collation fr_FR (LOCALE=‘fr_FR.utf8’)
```

has Unicode non-ASCII quotes `LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` and `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` instead of the normal ASCII double-quote. These fancy quotes are not delimiters for the SQL syntax, so they get interpreted as being part of the locale's name.

Try with:

```
create collation fr_FR (LOCALE="fr_FR.utf8");
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm always confused by quotes and double quotes in Postgres.